# Module imported in project interpreter but "Module Not Found" error keeps coming up

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, version-control, version

I have a module that exists in my project interpreter but when I try to run the import module it comes back with "ModuleNotFound" error. Module in question is gspread.

In Pycharm, my project interpreter shows this:

[image: Figure 1: project interpreter with gspread]

But when I run import gspread module in my code, it comes up with:

[image: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gspread']

When I take a look at my pip install, it shows the requirements are already satisfied:

[image: Requirement already satisfied]

And my python --version is Python 3.7.9:

[image: Python 3.7.9]

Here's a few caveats:
-I know this is on Windows
-I know I'm using pip install instead of a Docker container with pipenv

Can this be fixed in a Pipfile, or can I change settings in my IDE, or does this need to be fixed through the CLI? I'm guessing this error is coming from where my dependencies are pointing.

Comment: Look at run->Edit Configurations and validate your interpreter to be the one that package is installed on

Comment: @Aviv I took a look, and the configuration was not available, but it was definitely the IDE. I had to restart the computer to get the configuration to show up, but I got it to connect! Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: Glad it finally worked :) all luck! @GunterHerd

Comment: Typically need to restart the Python interpreter to get it to see new packages.